# Deploying from local to dev: pages do not work

Tags: migration

So I have deployed a WP that was local to a dev environment. I have done the following:

- Deployed files via FTP
- Imported DB via PHPMyAdmin
- Modified home and siteurl values in the _options table

So far, the landing page works fine, however as soon as I try to change page, it doesn't work.

It may be interesting to say that I have deployed onto a URL like http://dev.example.com/project-name/. I cannot put it at the root, this dev servers is used to present multiple projects.

I am not at ease with databases, deployments or htaccess things, so if you must explain with these things, please be gentle with me. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

1. Log into wp admin
2. Open Settings -> Permanent links
3. Check if site links works?
4. if NO check permitions to .htaccess in root
   folder. it shoudl be writable. and back to step 2.

Comment: There was something with the htaccess indeed, but the web host fixed that part, thanks for the guidance.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't import WordPress data via PHPMyAdmin. You should use the built-in WordPress importer/exporter, this way you will ensure that all permalinks are properly translated to your site's name. As Oleg suggested, try visiting permalink settings, this will flush the permalinks.

Comment: That would have saved me some time, I didn't know that existed. The thing of which I had to make sure was to change the siteurl and home vars in the _options table to that things works properly